# SQL Server Insert Fails with SET operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I'm getting this error:

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

I've been concatenating variables with '^', using XML path, but noticed certain characters would be formatted incorrectly (i.e `&` becomes `&amp;`), so I added:

```
, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'
```

But now I'm getting the error shown above.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT 
                   '^' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ST1.[planId]) AS [text()]
               FROM STable ST1
               WHERE ST1.cid = ST2.cid
               ORDER BY ST1.cid
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 2, 1000) [planId] 
FROM 
    dbo.STable ST2
```

Comment: you need to do a replace after the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(SELECT SUBSTRING(
            (
                SELECT 
                '^'+CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ST1.[planId])  AS [text()]
                FROM STable ST1
                WHERE ST1.cid= ST2.cid
                ORDER BY ST1.cid
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'
            ), 2, 1000) [planId] 
FROM dbo.STable ST2
,'&amp','&');
```

Answer (score 0):

This error depending of how is the SQL server configurated to allow COLLATEs. For your particular case using that server, you must specify the COLLATE (of various availables in your server) on each statement.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING((SELECT 
               '^' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ST1.[MilestoneId]) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS [text()]
           FROM STable ST1
           WHERE ST1.cid = ST2.cid
           ORDER BY ST1.cid
           FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 2, 1000) [planId] 
FROM 
dbo.STable ST2
```

Also recreate or alter the stored procedure (If you already created one) from a session with both QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON and ANSI_NULLS ON to avoid the problem going forward.